# knockout.jsでobservableArrayのデータ更新が反映されない

Tags: coffeescript, knockout.js

以下のHTMLを用意します。（値を３つだけ表示することが通常より特殊）

```
<div data-bind="foreach:{data:users, as:'user'}">
  <p data-bind="text:name"></p>
  <!-- 3つだけ表示 -->
  <ul data-bind="foreach:new Array(3)">
      <li data-bind="text:user.scores()[$index()]||0"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

次に、基本的なデータやメソッドを作成し、バインドします。

```
ko.applyBindings vm = new class
  constructor: ->
    @users = ko.observableArray([])
    @createUser = -> new class
      constructor: (name='')->
        @name = ko.observable(name)
        @scores = ko.observableArray([100])
```

そして、適当なデータを作成します。

```
user = vm.createUser()
user.name('takeshi')
user.scores.push(200)
vm.users.push(user)
```

プログラムが動き出してから３秒後にobservableArray内のデータの中身を書き換えます。

```
setTimeout ->
  vm.users()[0].scores()[0] = 999
  vm.users()[0].scores()[2] = 300
  # vm.users()[0].scores.push()
, 3000
```

データの内容が書き換わったため、htmlのli要素の内容が書き換わると思っているのですが、何故か書き換えることができません。

コメントアウトしているvm.users()[0].scores.push()を実行すると、observableArrayの内容更新が検出されるためかデータが反映されます。

この方法で反映されるため、特に問題ないのかもしれませんが、普通のやり方とは違うと思ったので質問しました。

このような場合どのようにデータを更新すればよいのでしょうか。

[こちら](http://jsfiddle.net/869abgcy/3/)にサンプルコードを用意させていただきました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObservableArray`が監視対象としているのはメソッドによる変更だけです。質問の例であれば、

```
vm.users()[0].scores([999,200,300])
```

と値を全て変更する、もしくは`scores`の要素自体をVMにするといった方針が良いかと思います。